# Importin `scipy.io` in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have Python 3.5 and when I try to import `scipy.io` it fails with an `ImportError`:

```
>>> from scipy import io
----> from scipy import io
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/__init__.py in <module>()
---> from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/__init__.py in <module>()
---> from .mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py in <module>()
---> from .miobase import get_matfile_version, docfiller
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py in <module>()
---> from six import reduce
ImportError: cannot import name 'reduce'
```

So, according to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), apparently in Python 3.5 recude changed from `six.reduce` to `six.functools.reduce`, and in fact I can import it with `import six` and `six.functools.reduce`.

So, looks like the 3.5 version of `scipy` has this bug (maybe?) which doens't happen for 2.7. Is there some way to fix this so I can use `scipy.io`?

I have CentOs with python 3.5.1, scipy 0.17.0 and numpy 1.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of `scipy` (same version number), after a successful import I see in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py'

```
from scipy._lib.six import reduce
```

My numpy is a little newer, but otherwise version look the same

And `six.py` does

```
if PY3:
    import builtins
    import functools
    reduce = functools.reduce
    zip = builtins.zip
    xrange = builtins.range
```

Comment: The `scipy._lib.six` import worked well here, however, I'm not sure how that solves my problem. When I try to import `scipy.io` it still fails. My goal is ultimately to import `scipy.io`!

Comment: So the `miobase.py` file uses `from six...`?  I wonder where that came from.  According to scipy github the switch to using `_lib.six` was done in 2014.  Something is funny in your installation.

Comment: There are some other SO `scipy.io` error questions; but a missing `_lib.six.py` file seems more common than your error.